# Can I add notes to a calendar for myself if I'm not the organiser

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I use the web version of Microsoft Outlook

I have a lot of meetings and often, I want to have notes for myself for each meeting. This works well but it means I have a calendar and notes in 2 different places.

I would like to be able to link to another file, such as an online Word document, from the calendar invite that only I can see. This means, instead of searching through directories for the document, I open the invite (which I'm going to do anyway to see the body of the calendar) and be able to click a link that takes me to the file I've "associated" with that invite (be it a one off invite or series)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ***the OneNote Add-in in Outlook*** could be able to satisfy you.

[image]

When using the OneNote Add-in, we can save the meeting into Online OneNote and click the "open in OneNote" to take notes online.
[image]
[image]

After the meeting, you could check your OneNote to review the notes you made.

Comment: Sadly, this is no different to the original problem. I can't access a previously created note from  OneNote (from within the invite). I'd have to open OneNote, and navigate to the note required. This is no different from my current situation (other than different software). Thanks though

Comment: Well, that's OK. However, apart from that, I'm afraid that there is no existed options or features for us to achieve the feature you would like. Maybe you could share you idea to Microsoft User Voice, there must be plenty of users agree with that. Hope Microsoft could add this feature in the future.